# Convert a list to another list in a better way

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

The following is an example of converting list to List

```
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Data
    public class A{
        private String name;
        private String value;
        private List<B> bList;
    }
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Data
    public class B{
        private Integer type;
        private Integer count;
    }
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Data
    public class C{
        private String name;
        private String value;
        private Integer type;
        private Integer count;
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A("test1", "test1", Arrays.asList(new B(1,1), new B(2,2)));
        A a1 = new A("test2", "test2", Arrays.asList(new B(2,2), new B(3,3)));
        List<A> aList = Arrays.asList(a, a1);

        List<C> rList = aList.stream()
                .map(t->{
                    List<B> bList = t.getBList();
                    List<C> c1List = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(B b : bList){
                        C c = new C(t.getName(), t.getValue(), b.getType(), b.getCount());
                        c1List.add(c);
                    }
                    return c1List;

        }).flatMap(x->x.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

In the main method, in addition to using the for loop to traverse bList, as shown below

```
 List<B> bList = t.getBList();
 List<C> c1List = new ArrayList<>();
 for(B b : bList){
     c = new C(t.getName(), t.getValue(), b.getType(), b.getCount());
     c1List.add(c);
 }
 return c1List;
```

I need to loop bList, then convert bList to c1List.but I feel like this code is a bit ugly, is there a more elegant way to implement this code？

Answer (score 0):

I will explain the code below please look at the comment on each line to understand it better

First converting the `A class` List into a Stream
Second each `A` is mapped into `B List` and since `A` other fields are needed they will be kept in the `aItem` as the code below shows, each `B List` is converted to a Stream.

so far we converted each A into a Stream of B while keeping the other fields.

Third each `B` is mapped into a `new C` using the `C constructor` and using the arguments of the `A` the has the list of B's - therefore the Stream of B's mapped into a Stream of C's

than the code continue as you did, just the lambda `x -> x.stream()` changed into method reference.

```java
  List<C> cList = aList.stream() // Stream<A>
         .map(aItem -> aItem.getBList().stream() // Stream<B>
                  .map(
     b -> new C(aItem.getName(), aItem.getValue(), b.getType(), b.getCount())
                      ) // Stream<C>
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())) // Stream<List<C>>
                .flatMap(Collection::stream) // Stream<C>
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```